# Unexpected SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input" is the error message I keep getting for the button underneath my form. I have marked where is underlined with * * in the code below (For further reference, it is at the very end on my sample code below and is only a single ">" that is underlined). I am going to turn grey soon, please help!

```
<form id="myForm2">

   <label for="milesToDrive">Miles to drive:
   </label><br>
   <input type="number" id="milesToDrive" name="milesToDrive" value="100"><br>

   <label for="xRatio">X Ratio:
   </label><br>
   <input type="number" id="xRatio" name="xRatio" value="3"><br>

   <label for="yRatio">Y Ratio:
   </label><br>
   <input type="number" id="yRatio" name="yRatio" value="1"><br><br>

</form>

<button type="submit" form="myForm1" value="Submit" onclick="return myCar.drive( document.getElementById("milesToDrive").value , document.getElementById("xRatio").value , document.getElementById("yRatio").value )">Drive the car</button*>*
```

Comment: Have a look at the double quotes on that line - even the syntax coloring is telling you something is wrong.

Comment: Yep issue is with the onclick attribute of button. Replace double quotes with single quotes for your `document.getElementById` and it will be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic part is here:

```
onclick="return myCar.drive( document.getElementById("milesToDrive").value , document.getElementById("xRatio").value , document.getElementById("yRatio").value )"
```

The quotes that start the onclick function are closed by the quotation mark that starts `milesToDrive`. To fix this, you can use single quotes to delimit the onclick function.

```
onclick='return myCar.drive( document.getElementById("milesToDrive").value , document.getElementById("xRatio").value , document.getElementById("yRatio").value )'
```

Alternatively, if you need to use both single and double quotes in your function, you can use `&quot;` to escape double quotes.

```
onclick="return myCar.drive( document.getElementById(&quot;milesToDrive&quot;).value , document.getElementById(&quot;xRatio&quot;).value , document.getElementById(&quot;yRatio&quot;).value )"
```